# Swift uniform typename not recognized

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, fragment-shader, uniform

Im trying to get a shader working in spritekit using swift. in the shader, i have three uniforms declared correctly as far as i can tell but I get the error: 
    program_source:8:1: error: unknown type name 'uniform'

on

```
uniform vec4 info;
uniform vec4 pixelSize;
uniform sampler2D innerImage;
```

full shader

```
uniform vec4 info; // x is time spent transitioning
// y is time it takes to transition

uniform vec4 pixelSize; // x is pixel size on the x
// y is pixel size on the y

uniform sampler2D innerImage;

void main()
{
    vec4 sceneColor = texture2D(u_texture,v_tex_coord);

    float radius = info.x / info.y;
    float distance = length(v_tex_coord - info.zw);

    vec2 innerGreyCircle = radius - pixelSize.xy * 25;
    vec2 outerColorCircle = radius + pixelSize.xy * 25;

    if(distance < radius)
    {
        //vec2 circle = radius - pixelSize.xy * 25;
        if(distance > innerGreyCircle.x || distance > innerGreyCircle.y)
        {
            vec2 tc = v_tex_coord;
            vec2 p = -1.0 + 2.0 * tc;
            float len = length(p);
            vec2 newTexCoord = tc + (p / len) * cos(len * 12.0f - info.x * 4.0f) * 1.0f;
            sceneColor = texture2D(innerImage,newTexCoord);//.xyz;//filter, newTexCoord).xyz;
        }

        float grey = dot(sceneColor.rgb, 1) / 3 * 1.5f;
        sceneColor = vec4(grey, grey, grey, 1);
    }
    else if(distance < outerColorCircle.x || distance < outerColorCircle.y)
    {
        vec2 tc = v_tex_coord;
        vec2 p = -1.0 + 2.0 * tc;
        float len = length(p);
        vec2 newTexCoord = tc + (p / len) * cos(len * 12.0f - info.x * 4.0f) * 1.0f;
        sceneColor = texture2D(innerImage,newTexCoord);//.xyz;//filter,       newTexCoord).xyz;
}

    gl_FragColor = sceneColor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you dont need the declarations at the beginning when using something in the combination of spritekit, swift, and glsl.